# How to make the P-Trap sloped

Tags: drain, plumbing-fixture, p-trap

I am remodeling my kitchen, and am completely redoing the drain system because I have to move it over. I am looking online, and it seems that the part after the P trap to the vertical part of the drain pipe needs to be slanted. How do you make it slanted when the parts I see only make it straight.

Does it need to be slanted?

Thanks for any feedback!
[image]

(see image to see what I mean by slanted part)

Answer (score 4):

Most of them are 89 degree bends (not 90 degrees) so they have about 1 degree of slope which is all that is needed.

most diagrams exaggerate the slope so that the reader can see it, and so that the picture will fit on the page.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is adjust the P-trap up slightly.

Once you have your tail piece cut and in place you slip your P-trap over the end of it and just slide it up ever so little in order to achieve the small slope before you tighten down the slip nut.

Do not cut the tail piece too short, you can make it shorter but it *very difficult too make it longer* and there is room in the top of the P-trap to slide and adjust the slip joint.

Sliding the P-trap slip joint up will give you a very slight slope and a **little is all you need** and you do not want so much  that it makes the slip joint is too far out of skew resulting in a leaky seal.

Comment: But... I cut it 3 times and it's still too short!!

Comment: On a more serious note, use a short level. Get the pipe perfectly horizontal, then move the trap up so the bubble is slightly off center. Done!